# Adding class based on multiple URL's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an accordion menu and my problem is that I want the menu sub menu to stay open when one of the links in the sub menu is clicked.  I have come up with a a javascript function to add the class that looks like this:

```js
$(function(){
   $('#collapseTwo' + location.pathname.split('/register_deal.aspx').slice(-1)).addClass('in');  
});
```

The code above works and keeps the accordion open when the link is clicked. When I try to add another function for the next page it doesn't work.  Example:

```js
$(function(){
   $('#collapseTwo' + location.pathname.split('/find_deals.aspx').slice(-1)).addClass('in');  
});
```

I was thinking that I could just duplicate the function for each page since they are all using the same menu.  I am not sure why it is not working.  Any help on this would be great. Thank you!

Here is an example of the menu:

```html
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
         <!-- <li><a id="side_deal_reg" ClientIdMode="Static" runat="server">Deal Registration</a></li> -->
         <li><a href="<%=ResolveClientUrl(homeDirectory + "sfdc_deal_registration/find_deals.aspx")%>">Review Deals</a></li>
            <li><a href="<%=ResolveClientUrl(homeDirectory + "sfdc_deal_registration/register_deal.aspx")%>">Register a Deal</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How does your menu structure look? Like ...<div id="collapseTwo">... what else?

Comment: Added my html to the original post

Comment: what value does `location.pathname.split('/find_deals.aspx').slice(-1)` produce?